# One Average Spline for each Column in Highcharts Combination Chart

Tags: highcharts

i am quite new to Highcharts and i am a little bit stucked.
I am trying to add a average line (spline) to each bar (column) in a combination chart. The average line shall not be displayed in the middle, it sall be displayed over the related bar, as i tried to show in this picture.
[picture to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrSVE.png)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can add new xAxis that you can use to add your spline series in right places.

```
xAxis: [{
  min: 0,
  max: 3,
  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
  tickPixelInterval: 0
}, {
  categories: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 19,
  visible: false
}],
```

In this case I am making the second xAxis much more dense. Here you can see how both of my axes looks here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/feqq1eog/1/

To hide second axis you can use **visible: false** parameter.

Here you can find an example how it can work:

http://jsfiddle.net/feqq1eog/4/

Comment: Thanks! That works really great! How can i hide the y-value in the top left corner of the tooltip, that appears when i hover over the points of the average line?

Comment: I think you want to hide value of second xAxis from tooltip. To hide this value you can use headerFormat: http://jsfiddle.net/feqq1eog/5/ If you are satisfied with my examples, please mark the answer as correct.